# Specifying UTF8 Encoding When Importing a CSV to VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, excel, utf-8

I am importing data from a csv file into my vb.net application. Below is the current code I am using to achieve this:

```
    Dim myImportConnectionString As String = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" & txtboxSelectFile.Text & "';Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;IMEX=1"""
    Dim MyImportConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    MyImportConnection.ConnectionString = myImportConnectionString
    MyImportConnection.Open()
    Dim myImportAdapterString As String = "select * from [" & mySheet & "$]"
    Dim MyImportCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(myImportAdapterString, MyImportConnection)
    Dim myImportDataAdapter As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(MyImportCommand)
    Dim myImportDataTable As New System.Data.DataTable
    myImportDataAdapter.Fill(myImportDataTable)
    dgvFirst.DataSource = myImportDataTable
    myImportDataAdapter.Dispose()
    MyImportCommand.Dispose()
    MyImportConnection.Close()
    MyImportConnection.Dispose()
    GC.Collect()
```

The problem I have is that the data is UTF8 encoded. When I import it, any special characters are being displayed incorrectly. The only way I can open the csv file and use the correct encoding is by opening it manually, using Excel, and importing the data to a new Excel file.

Is there any way I can specify the encoding to use when the file is being automatically imported into a vb.net datatable so that foreign characters are displayed correctly?

Many Thanks :)

Comment: If you are trying to read a CSV file, isn't what you are doing a bit overkill?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576580/convert-csv-file-from-any-type-to-utf-8)

Comment: Why are you using OLEDB to query a csv file!??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `;CharacterSet=ANSI` as input encoding to the `Extended Properties`:

Replace

```
Dim myImportConnectionString As String = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='"_ 
   & txtboxSelectFile.Text & "';Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;IMEX=1"""
```

by

```
Dim myImportConnectionString As String = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='"_ 
   & txtboxSelectFile.Text & "';Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;IMEX=1"";CharacterSet=ANSI"
```

(idea comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28629443/using-vb-net-to-import-my-csv-file-to-my-access-db))