# Characters replaced with replacement character when loading characters in Access

Tags: json, vb.net, ms-access

I have encountered an issue in my VB.NET code where certain characters, such as "ü", are getting replaced with a "replacement character" when loading data into my application.
Here's an example of the code snippet:

```
Dim adoConntestBks As New ADODB.Connection
adoConntestBks.ConnectionString = CommonAccessMethods.GetConnectionString(path_testBksDb)
adoConntestBks.Open()
strQuery = "INSERT INTO testBook ([ID],[testID],[LocaleID],[testBookPublisherID],[Description],[TitleHTML],[ColophonHTML],[TablOfContentJSON],[TableOfContentHTML]) " &
 "VALUES (" & testBookID &
 " ," & testID &
 " ," & localeId &
 " ," & currenttestBookPublisherID &
 " ,'" & testBookDescription.Replace("'", "''") & "'" &
 " ,'" & GetFirstFileFromFolder(path_activetestBks & nameOfFolder & "\title\", "*.html", True).Trim().Replace("'", "''") & "'" &
 " ,'" & GetFirstFileFromFolder(path_activetestBks & nameOfFolder & "\colophon\", "*.html", True).Trim().Replace("'", "''") & "'" &
 " ,'" & GetFirstFileFromFolder(path_activetestBks & nameOfFolder & "\toc\", "*.json", True).Trim().Replace("'", "''") & "'" &
 " ,'" & GetFirstFileFromFolder(path_activetestBks & nameOfFolder & "\toc\", "*.html", False).Trim().Replace("'", "''") & "');"
 adoConntestBks.Execute(strQuery)
```

In the above code, I'm inserting values into a table called `testBook` using an INSERT statement.
The values are retrieved from various sources, including file contents. However, when certain characters like "ü" are present in the json file, they are being replaced with a "replacement character" during the execution of the query.
How can I ensure that the characters are correctly loaded without being replaced by the replacement character?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried Command Parameters to specify the Type of the values as suggested by @Jimi, but the special characters like `ü` are still being replaced by a replacement character �

```
        Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
        cmd.ActiveConnection = adoConnTestBks
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestBook ([ID],[TestID],[LocaleID],[TestBookPublisherID],[Description],[TitleHTML],[ColophonHTML],[TablOfContentJSON]) " &
            "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

        cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("ID", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , TestBookID))
        cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("TestID", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , TestID))
        cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("LocaleID", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , localeId))
        cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("TestBookPublisherID", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , currentTestBookPublisherID))
        cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("Description", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, Len(TestBookDescription), TestBookDescription))
        cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("TitleHTML", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, Len(GetFirstFileFromFolder(path_activeTestBks & nameOfFolder & "\title\", "*.html", True).Trim()), GetFirstFileFromFolder(path_activeTestBks & nameOfFolder & "\title\", "*.html", True).Trim()))
        cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("ColophonHTML", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, Len(GetFirstFileFromFolder(path_activeTestBks & nameOfFolder & "\colophon\", "*.html", True).Trim()), GetFirstFileFromFolder(path_activeTestBks & nameOfFolder & "\colophon\", "*.html", True).Trim()))
        cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("TablOfContentJSON", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, Len(GetFirstFileFromFolder(path_activeTestBks & nameOfFolder & "\toc\", "*.json", True).Trim()), GetFirstFileFromFolder(path_activeTestBks & nameOfFolder & "\toc\", "*.json", True).Trim()))
        'cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("TableOfContentHTML", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, Len(GetFirstFileFromFolder(path_activeTestBks & nameOfFolder & "\toc\", "*.html", False).Trim()), GetFirstFileFromFolder(path_activeTestBks & nameOfFolder & "\toc\", "*.html", False).Trim()))
        cmd.Execute()
```

Comment: What is this "replacement character"

Comment: The replacement character is �

Comment: Maybe add encoding to your connection string? `CharSet=utf8`

Comment: You should really use Command Parameters to specify the Type of the values you insert. This would allow to specify `adVarWChar` as the Type and also eliminate the contrived use of `.Replace("'", "''")` and all other string concatenation shenanigans. Possibly, move to ADO.NET

Comment: Thank you for suggesting Command Parameters. I gave it a try, but I am still getting � I updated my question to include your suggestion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specifying UTF8 Encoding When Importing a CSV to VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38738247/specifying-utf8-encoding-when-importing-a-csv-to-vb-net)

Comment: Your complaint is about the JSON file, but it doesn't appear you have used `adVarWChar` for that -- You should show what `GetFirstFileFromFolder()` is doing and specify how the JSON file is encoded (it's usually UTF-8). I.e., make sure you're reading it correctly

Comment: `adLongVarWChar` and `adVarWChar` did not do the trick (replacement character persists). `GetFirstFileFromFolder()` only gets the name of the name of the 1st file found in any given folder